# Inflate Views in PreferenceActivity? OnClickListeners not working

Tags: java, android, preferenceactivity

I have a preference xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<com.example.checkboxtest.MyCheckBox android:title="Preference 1" android:key="alert"
android:widgetLayout="@layout/preference_checkbox"/>
```

Then my layout - preference_checkbox

```
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ax" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<com.example.checkboxtest.MyChckBox 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/alerttt"

/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here it is my PreferenceActivity:

```
MyCheckBox cb = (MyCheckBox) findPreference("alert");


    LayoutInflater lif = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);



View v = lif.inflate(R.layout.preference_checkbox, null);

MyChckBox c = (MyChckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.alerttt);

    c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d("DEBUG", "clicked");

        }
    });
```

The problem is that onclicklistener is never triggered, even I inflated the layout. What could be wrong?

Also I have checked few similar topics here but I couldn't find the proper answer:

[onclick not working for inflated layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037775/onclick-not-working-for-inflated-layout)
[Inflated layout's buttons onClick listener not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444516/inflated-layouts-buttons-onclick-listener-not-working)

Comment: Use CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener instead.

Comment: I know. But still since CheckBox is a Button, then it should work with OnClickListeners also.

Comment: Well, see if you can convince it to be more button-like then.